# Routing error in Rails4 passenger and apache

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I am trying to deploy my Rails4 app locally(I just want to it run on my Mac). I use Passenger and Apache for deployment. After some configuration, my home page works fine. But when I click any links on my homepage or go to any other path, I got this error:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
```

So I added this line to my httpd.conf file in apache

```
RailsEnv development
```

And now I got this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/Users/joey/Sites/index.html"
No route matches [POST] "/Users/joey/Sites/index.html" (If I make a post request)
```

My project directory is  "/Users/joey/Sites/depot" and this is my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName depot.joeyhu.info
DocumentRoot /Users/joey/Sites/depot/public/
RailsEnv development
<Directory /Users/joey/Sites/depot/public>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

LoadModule passenger_module  /Users/joey/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /Users/joey/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50
  PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/joey/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
```

This is my rails log(development.log and production.log basically show the same error):

```
I, [2014-09-12T10:31:17.300176 #41946]  INFO -- : Started GET    "/Users/joey/Sites/index.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-12 10:31:17 -0700
F, [2014-09-12T10:31:17.300964 #41946] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Users/joey/Sites/index.html"):
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in  `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.2) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
passenger (4.0.50) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
passenger (4.0.50) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (4.0.50) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
passenger (4.0.50) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Except the root_url, it loooks like whatever path I go to, it will make a get or post request to the URL "/Users/joey/Sites/index.html" which doesn't make sense. Can someone help me? Thanks!

I am using Rails 4.1.2.

Comment: what URL are you entering in the browser, for that log? You should probably be entering `http://localhost` to access the root of your application. i think you may be entering something else?